# Trouble applying gesture recognizer to navigationbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

In my iPad Application I have multiple views on a screen.

What I want to do is apply a double tap Gesture Recognizer to the Navigation Bar.  But I had no success, however when the same gesture recognizer applied to that view it works.

Here is the code I am using:

```
// Create gesture recognizer, notice the selector method
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneFingerTwoTaps = 
[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneFingerTwoTaps)] autorelease];

// Set required taps and number of touches
[oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps];
```

This works on view, but when this is done:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps]
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you need to subclass UINavigationBar, override the init button in it and add your gesture recognizer there.

So say you make a subclass called 'CustomNavigationBar' - in your m file you would have an init method like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) 
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight;
        swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeRight:)];
        [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
        [swipeRight setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
        [swipeRight setEnabled:YES];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you need to set the class name of your navigation bar in interface builder to the name of your subclass.

[image]

Also it's handy to add a delegate protocol to your navigation bar to listen for methods sent at the end of your gestures. For example - in the case of the above swipe right:

```
@protocol CustomNavigationbarDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)customNavBarDidFinishSwipeRight;
@end
```

then in the m file - on the gesture recognised method (whatever you make it) you can trigger this delegate method.

Hope this helps

Comment: :Thank-you very much for your solution.Actually,i dint try it. Instead i added an custom button onto the navigation bar and added the gesture recognizer to the button.I know this is not the proper approach, but it did the work:)

Comment: Shouldn't you return `self` in the `initWithCoder` method?

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else viewing this, here is a much simpler way to do this.

```
[self.navigationController.view addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerTwoTaps];
```