# Add gesture recogniser to navigation bar

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a pan gesture recogniser on the navigation bar:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:self.panGestureRecognizer];
```

but it doesn't seem to trigger the gesture. Any ideas why?

Comment: where are you initializing the gesture?

Comment: The gesture is initialised properly, because it works fine when I attach it to the main view - it fails only on navigation bar.

Comment: Do you sure, that your navigationBar and navigationController not nil at that moment? :-) Please check it by putting breakpoint or NSLog

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167188/trouble-applying-gesture-recognizer-to-navigationbar

Answer (score 2):

first create pangesture object.
add gesture recognizer to navigationbar view.

then call your gesture recognizer method.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pushVC:)];

[self.nav.view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];


-(void)pushVC:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        pushVC *pushvc = [[pushVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"pushVC" bundle:nil];

        [self.nav pushViewController:pushvc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `self.nav.view`? `UINavigationBar` doesn't have a `view` property.

Comment: @user623396:self.nav is object of UINavigationController.

Comment: Ok, I tried adding it to `navigationController.view` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @user623396: it is work for me. try according to my way.